# fundamental complex integral( in Conway's book)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am reading Conway's Functions of One Complex Variable. I have some trouble in doing some exercise.

Find $\int_\gamma(z^2-1)^{-1}dz$, where $\gamma$ is a path. $\gamma(t)=1+e^{it}$ for $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$.

Find $\int_\gamma(z^2-1)^{-1}dz$, where $\gamma$ is a path. $\gamma(t)=2e^{it}$ for $-\pi\leq t\leq \pi$.

These two are similar. They are in Chapter 4 Section where Riemann-Stieltjes integral is just defined. Since Cauchy theorem is introduced in later chapter, I guess we can solve these without using Cauchy theorem or its corollaries.

I know
$$
\int_\gamma\frac 1{z^2-1}=\frac12\int_\gamma\frac 1{z-1}-\frac1{z+1}dz=\frac 12\int_\gamma\frac 1{z-1}dz-\frac 12\int_\gamma\frac1{z+1}dz
$$
What should I do next?

I know the question I ask is very fundamental but I am stuck. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of a complex integral like this is

$$\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt$$

where $a$ and $b$ are the endpoints of the interval parameterizing $\gamma$. So here, $\gamma(t) = 1 + e^{it}$ and $a = 0$, $b = 2\pi$, so

\begin{align*}
\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z^2 - 1} dz &= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{(1 + e^{it})^2 - 1} ie^{it} dt \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ie^{it} dt}{2e^{it} + e^{2it}} \\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{i dt}{2 + e^{it}}
\end{align*}

I'll leave it to you to finish evaluating the integral. The other one is done similarly.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, it is what I've got.

Comment: can you give some hint of computing the integral?